# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to implement Paypal dodirect method for user can do payment directly on my website instead of redirecting to user

so for that i have added this URL as https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl

and i am using following code

```
PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient objpaypalapiaainterfaceclient = new PayPalAPIAAInterfaceClient("paypalapiaa");
        CustomSecurityHeaderType objcustomsecurityheadertype = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
        objcustomsecurityheadertype.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
        objcustomsecurityheadertype.Credentials.Signature = "a8ft-8ji.2tzocnfshfjj4ahgxn4avlxzply8bmsbupxafkbty2--c6p";
        objcustomsecurityheadertype.Credentials.Username = "fred_1350925179_biz_api1.gmail.com";
        objcustomsecurityheadertype.Credentials.Password = "1350925199";

        DoDirectPaymentReq objdodirectpaymentreq = new DoDirectPaymentReq();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest = new DoDirectPaymentRequestType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails = new DoDirectPaymentRequestDetailsType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentAction = new PaymentActionCodeType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentAction = PaymentActionCodeType.Sale;
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
        //objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.InvoiceID = "1";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"].ToString();

        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CreditCardType = CreditCardTypeType.MasterCard;

        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner = new PayerInfoType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.PayerName = new PersonNameType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal.currencyID = CurrencyCodeType.USD;
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address = new AddressType();
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.PaymentDetails.OrderTotal.Value = "120";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CreditCardNumber ="1111222233334444";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CVV2 = "258";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.ExpMonth = 9;
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.ExpYear = 2013;
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Payer = "rahularyansharma@gmail.com";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.PayerName.FirstName = "Shakti";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.PayerName.LastName = "Kapoor";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address.Street1 ="test address";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address.CityName = "Atlanta";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address.StateOrProvince = "ga";
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address.Country = CountryCodeType.US;
        objdodirectpaymentreq.DoDirectPaymentRequest.DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails.CreditCard.CardOwner.Address.PostalCode = "12345";
        DoDirectPaymentResponseType objdodirectpaymentresponsetype = objpaypalapiaainterfaceclient.DoDirectPayment(ref objcustomsecurityheadertype, objdodirectpaymentreq);
```

now when i am run this code throwing followin exception

**'
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

Answer (score 1):

You can confirm the SSL protocol for  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com, using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest. The screenshot shows that it supports TLS 1.2 [image] You will need to add the following two lines to your code at the point of making httpclient call:

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Sample: [image]
The implementation should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i cannot add this as a comment/question.

It seems like one of certificates for paypal is not in the trusted list.

Can you try download paypal root certificate and install it as trusted CA?

I think this two links can help you: 
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html
and
http://raysilvadotnet.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/problema-system-net-webexception-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssltls-secure-channel/
(sorry, cannot insert more than 2 links as normal links)

Also, please make sure you authenticating via login/password not certificate. If you are using certificate for API, you should follow last paragraph of [this link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/apiCredentials/)