# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asmx

I am using an asmx webservice client to connect to a backend web service and we have multiple environments .In one of the server ,am getting error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" but every other environments it works fine. I referred  below articles already and none of it helped.

[The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320900/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

[The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945470/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure)

[HttpWebRequest: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006333/httpwebrequest-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

[HttpWebRequest The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628440/httpwebrequest-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Comment: can you capture a [system.net trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-configure-network-tracing) and add details to the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the issue is server specific ,you may be running into any issue
>   with Server Certification validation check (because of the Root
>   Certificate missing) or CRL check failure ,then following code might
>   help.Add this to your project and verify

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Please note that this is not a good way as we are just making all the ServerCertificateValidation always true .

If server validation is the issue,the correct way to do is to make sure your you can successfully access the https url from the machine.You can browse to the URL using any browser and it should be successfully be able to browse without any warning.if any warning comes(e.g. certificate not trusted),verify the error and make sure you have the required root certificate installed etc

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am getting the same error and when I try to access the URL in chrome, It is showing a message box and asks to confirm one certificate from list, When I confirms it goes off. But in the code error remains there

Comment: I tried all the possible ways but still got the same error. I have posted full details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676727/webexception-the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-b . Please see if anyone faced the same issue.