# UFT API Testing: Could Not Create SSL/TLS Secure Channel

Tags: web-services, hp-uft, web-api-testing, uft14, uft-api

I am getting `Could Not Create SSL/TLS Secure Channel` in UFT API Testing.
we specified HTTP RequestHeaders in event handlers and End Point address as well.
I could not give much details as we have restricted to provide.
Any Idea why we are getting this error? I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941237/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-for-httpwebrequ) but I'm still getting error after providing:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its an certificate incompatibility, e.g the certificate only allows TLS 1.2 while your client only supports TLS 1.1, or other algorithms.