# The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, ssl

I try to call a remote REST Web API.
My tests in Postman are successful.
but in .Net Framework 4.5.2  and using a HttpClient I get this error:

The request was aborted. Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

As mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859790/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel), I set the followings:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityPortocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Also, I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44941237/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-for-httpwebrequ)

but nothing has changed.

thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: So when you debugged both results with fiddler to check the differences, what did you find ?

Comment: a key difference in raw requests! in postman raw request, the host is IP:443, but in .Net host is just IP (with no port Number!). I think the question has now changed to "How to set port Number in my .Net request?" Or "How postman connects to port 443 without any pointing to the it?!"

Comment: Even, when I explicitly add port Number (443) to my client address, the host in raw request is Just IP(with No port Number!)